# Rails markdown editor with live preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

Are there any markdown editors that integrate with rails (eg in a gem) and offer live preview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout [markdown.js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) and [showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown). You could rig them up to parse whatever the markdown input is whenever certain events fire (i.e. a user releasing a key when typing in the markdown textarea). I'm not aware of any other embeddable markdown editors with live previews, but it seems it would be easy enough to make one with one of these libraries.

Comment: Nice, haven't seen that one before. Looks pretty cool!

Comment: @Dawid, the problem with epiceditor is that it's really hard to integrate with asset pipeline

Comment: EpicEditor's new url - https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor

Answer (score 8):

Check out the gem below, its not well documented but seems to work

https://github.com/zethussuen/epic-editor-rails