# Implementing preview for markdown text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, redcarpet

I am working on Ruby on Rails project and I have implemented markdown syntax for some text descriptions in my project using [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) gem.

It works like charm allowing to convert markdown text to HTML as simply as

`<%= markdown some_text_variable %>`

But now I want to implement preview feature rendering just small part of the full text.

The following naive construction

`<%= markdown some_text_variable[0..preview_length] %>`

will not work because it can easily break down MD syntax resulting in confusing constructions (imagine, for example, spliting original string on the half of image link).

I came up with

`<%= markdown some_text_variable[0..preview_length].split(/\r?\n/)[0..-2].join("\r\n")) %>`

but it does not deal, for example, with code blocks.

Is there any way to implement such kind of preview for MD text?

Comment: Can you iterate over the array of markdown syntax and check for a regex that matches a newline and any markdown characters? If true, (has opening and closing), print the slice, and if false, (has opening but no closing and no open tags until next closing or newline), add on closing tag and print the slice?

Comment: @BottledSmoke Isn't it overcomplicated? And how to deal with lists which have no closing tags? I came up with idea of just slice on new line (but not less then certain amount of characters). But it also does not deal with lists...

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that you can use markdown and showdown. You'll have to forgive me. I just woke up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [markdown.js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) and / or [showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) should work. [Here's a StackO with the same question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440037/rails-markdown-editor-with-live-preview). I personally have used showdown in an Ember app before to render a live preview of the text as it's being typed (via 2-way data binding), and it worked flawlessly.

In the fiddle below, I wrote a little Showdown parser that takes in a string of markdown, splits it on a newline (returns an array of tags), and iterates through the array. On each iteration, it removes the tags, checks the length of the resulting string, and then compares it to the max character count for the preview. Once the next iteration surpasses the max character count, it returns the preview. The do loop ensures that you will always get at least one blob of html as a preview.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bottledsmoke/rdyLm39s/9/)

```
$(function() {
  var converter = new Showdown.converter();
  var previewMax = 200;

  $('button').click(function() {        
    var content = $('#markdown').val(),
        charCount = 0,
        i = 0,
        output = '';

    if (!content) {
      return $('div.preview').html("Please enter some text.");
    }

    var mark = converter.makeHtml(content);
    var mark_arr = mark.split('\n');

    while (charCount < previewMax) {
      var html = mark_arr[i];
      var text = htmlStrip(html);            

      if ((charCount + text.length) > previewMax) {
        var overflow = (charCount + text.length) - previewMax;
        var clipAmount = text.length - overflow;
        html = jQuery.truncate(mark_arr[i], { length: clipAmount });
        }

      output += html;
      charCount += text.length;
      i++;
    };

    $('div.preview').html(output);
    $('div.full').html(mark);
  });

  function htmlStrip (html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
    return text;
  }
});
```

---

### REVISION

I updated the function using [jQuery Truncate](https://github.com/pathable/truncate) to cut the final string into an elipses so that all your previews are the same length as the others. Also, I realized that the original function returned a long string of undefined' over and over when no text was entered, so there is a check to eliminate that. Since this loop will always return at least one html item now, I changed the do loop to a while loop for easier reading. Finally, if you want your truncation to always end at a word boundary, pass the `words: true` option when you call it. Obviously, this will not give you the same level of truncation for every preview, but it will improve legibility. That's it!

Comment: Thank you for great idea! But if I render a chunk of the data it will contain HTML tags so I will not be able to just slice the string in the middle...

Comment: Yeah I realized that, so I edited my answer. Will something like that work?

Comment: IMO the hardest part is to find out exact regexp to use for your algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, you don't need a regex. It was St. Pattys yesterday. My head wasn't right when the morning hit like a freight train. I've revised my answer yet again with a fiddle that should solve your problems or at least point you in the right direction (no regex involved).

Comment: Just wow! Thank you so much for your efforts and time you spend on that issue! I would really upvote at least 10 times if it was possible :)

Comment: Anytime. We're all in this together :)

Comment: Yes, for sure! But you delivered really amazing piece of code!!

Answer (score 3):

I want to share my preview version it was quite simple with [showdown.js](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) and [prism.js](http://prismjs.com/) syntax highlighting.

`Prism.js` is syntaxing easily with JavaScript and CSS. All you need to pick specific languages and download it to assets folder. Or you can specify it to specific pages.

This is going to happen in realtime preview, in a form.

**In Rails form:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", rows: 10 %>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1> Preview Markdown </h1>
  <div class="form-group markdownOutput"></div>
</div>
```

**And add this script right below a form page.**

```
<script>
function mkdown(){
  var converter  = new showdown.Converter(),
      $post_body = $("#post_body");

  // This line will keep adding new rows for textarea. 
  function postBodyLengthDetector(post_body){
    var lines = post_body.val().split("\n");
    post_body.prop('rows', lines.length+5);
  }


  // Textarea rows in default '10', when focusing on this. It will expand. 
  $post_body.focus(function(){
    postBodyLengthDetector($(this));
    $('.markdownOutput').html(converter.makeHtml($post_body.val()));
  });

  // All simple magic goes here, each time when texting anything into textarea
  //it will be generated to markdown. You are able to see preview right below of textarea.
  $post_body.keyup(function() {
    postBodyLengthDetector($(this));
      var value = $( this ).val(),
          html  = converter.makeHtml(value);
          $('.markdownOutput').html(html);
  });
}
$(mkdown);
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", mkdown);
</script>
```